# How to debug stored procedure when Oracle is running in Docker?

Tags: oracle, docker, debugging, plsql

I used to debug Oracle stored procedure using Oracle SQL Developer. But somehow after DB team migrates the DB to docker environment, I receives the following error message when try to start a debugger on a stored procedure:

```
Connecting to the database XXX.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', '0' )
ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
ORA-12533: TNS:illegal ADDRESS parameters
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
Process exited.
```

According to server team, they have enable a debug port (e.g. 40100) for my debugger to connect to, but still fail to connect to.

Can anybody have any suggestion on this?

Comment: i suspect you need docker to expose also the listener port (by default 1521/tcp)
$ docker run -d -p 1521:1521 ...